# Ajax response having special characters

Tags: ajax

I am using AJAX for validation. I am using servlet in server side.I am writing in the response as follows

response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.getWriter().write("123");

The response XMl is coming as invalid if i have any special charcters like ©
,® and soon in IE.
Please let me know how to get the response xml as valid by having the above special characters in it.

Comment: not entirely sure but as a wild guess, I'd suggest adding JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in your system variables.

Answer (score 0):

Download Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils. It has a function for escaping things like ©